# Best process to swap domain used as nameserver for a server

Tags: bind, nameserver

This is a question relating to process and minimising downtime.    I have a Ubuntu/Bind configuration that serves a number of domains.

The nameservers are set through 123reg to use example1.uk and all domains point to ns1 and ns2 at this domain.

I would like to drop this domain and use example2.uk  (example2 currently uses example1 as its name servers!)

What is the best process for achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note both your old setup and a new one are not recommended for best performance. It's better for example3.uk to use ns1.example3.uk (same domain), because the glue records will make resolution slightly faster.

This answer is however exactly for what you asked.

First test if the new server resolves properly:

```
dig example3.uk @ns1.example2.uk    # from the Internet *and* from your office; all domains along example3.uk
```

Secondly change your zone files to:

```
example3.uk   IN NS ns1.example1.uk   # old 
example3.uk   IN NS ns2.example1.uk   # old
example3.uk   IN NS ns1.example2.uk   # new
example3.uk   IN NS ns2.example2.uk   # new
```

Repeat for all zone files example2-example9.

Check if all your bind daemons serve updated zones.

Now change the delegation for all domains (not *your* zone file, the 123reg-managed entries usually available through some registrar's web panel), replace NS *.example1.uk with *.example2.uk everywhere.

Now you can change your zone files again to remove *.example1.uk from NS and this time also from SOA:

```
example3.uk   IN SOA ns1.example2.uk  .....    # change the SOA too
example3.uk   IN NS ns1.example2.uk
example3.uk   IN NS ns2.example2.uk
```

Now you might want to remove yourself from the delegation of example1.uk at registrar's panel. And after the TTL passes (could be even 1 week!), you can stop serving example1.uk zone.

Comment: Thanks for the response.   Based on your first comment that would suggest over 10 different sets(ns1,ns2) of nameserver!   Or would you limit it to one nameserver set per domain so example1.uk, example1.uk.co.uk example1.uk.org.uk would all use ns.example1.uk?  Seems like a lot of nameservers.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself very well.   I understood that what you were saying.    I'm just saying that ns1.example1.uk, ns2.example1.uk, ns1.example2.uk, ns2.example2.uk ....   ns1.example9.uk, ns2.example9.uk is A LOT of nameservers set up at 123reg.   Does it really need to be that complicated?  Now also some of my domains are the same but with different TLDs.  So in those cases would you just have ns1.example1.uk, ns2.example1.uk  for all example1 TLDs.   Always willing to learn!

Comment: Yes, there would be a lot of different records at the registrar. But you only set them once and forget about them. That's a normal practice.